# How to get interest group id as integer in Mailchimp API

Tags: ruby, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When trying to send a campaign to a interest group via the API, the segment_opts object requires  "An array containing integers, each representing a group id."

The docs are here:
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/

Under recipients -> segment opts -> segment types = "Interest segments - Interests".

In the Mailchimp interface I'm able to see the group id as in integer, but using the API all the id's I get are strings such as:

```
{"category_id"=>"514d2280e8",
 "list_id"=>"7753bdb3c1",
 "id"=>"fd766fdh5c",
 "name"=>"Single Group",
```

How can I get the group id as an integer so I can send a campaign to a group??

Comment: Which of the strings in your example is supposed to be a group ID?

Comment: @hoffm the category_id and id both have an integer equivalent required for the API. category_id is the "group", and id is the sub-group/interest.